# Optimizing an assemly for .cpp file

Tags: windows, assembly, x86

I have a question on optimizing an assembly file that I got from a .cpp file!!
This is my hw from computer organization class.
The hw is as follows.
I have to write a program that calculate dot product of two vectors and generate .asm file. Then, I have to optimize the .asm file and compare the execution time by using QueryPerformanceCounter on Visual Studio. I generated the .asm file and found the loop part in it. I am trying to learn the basic assembly language to optimize the assembly. However, I have no idea how to execute the .asm file. My professor mentioned about linking between .cpp file and the assembly but no idea what that mean. 
Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Your professor wants you to tweak assembly code generated from C++, and gave you no directions on how to assemble the asm? Sounds like the worst class in existence.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but a quick search turned up [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271627/Assembly-Programming-with-Visual-Studio-2010-2012) on codeproject which at least *looks* useful. If your professor doesn't insist on assembling and linking in an external assembly source file, you could also try inline assembly.

Comment: He talked about how to generate the assembly code but did not show how to do it. I figured out to generate the assembly code and now the problem is to link .cpp file and the optimized assembly code.

Comment: Must say I agree with @JonathonReinhart that if your professor gave you no direction on how to assemble the asm, that's a really poor class.  But I find it a little hard to believe a professor would make such a grievous mistake. Is it possible you took a class that's a little over your head?  Maybe you don't have some of the prerequisites the class requires?

Comment: I took prerequisites before I took this organization class..and it was the class with same professor... His lecture is not clear... and the professor require us to know the assembly language that we did not learn in prerequisite class..lol

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your professor is asking, you need to do this in steps:

1. Create a function in C++ to calculate the dot product.
2. In `main()`, call this function in a loop many thousands of times, say 5000.
3. Add a call to `QueryPerformanceCounter` before and after this loop.
4. Run your program and note the total time it took to call your function 5000 times.
5. Use the compiler to generate assembly for your function.  Save that assembly to an .asm file and then optimize it.
6. Assemble the .asm file with an appropriate assembler in order to generate an .obj file.
7. Compile your .cpp file and link it with the .obj file you generated in the step above to produce an .exe file.
8. Run the program again and note the total time it took to call your optimized function 5000 times.
9. Compare the two measurements (and note how the compiler is probably better at optimizing than you are).

You don't say what compiler, assembler or hardware platform you're using, so I can't provide more details than that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Im using visual studio on windows.. The steps you suggested look right but the thing I want to know is how. I have done upto fifth step. After that I dont know how to generate .obj file with visual studio and link .cpp file with .obj file!

Comment: You can't generate an .obj file with Visual Studio.  You need an assembler to do that.  Did your professor not provide or recommend an assembler to use?  Assuming you're on an x86 platform, you can find a list of assemblers [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_assemblers), some of which are free and open source.  Scroll down to the "x86" table.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Sure it helps.  Well, it will help once the OP accomplishes the miracle of figuring out how to assemble and link an asm file to a VS C++ file. ;-)  I suspect missing prerequisites.